# Issue when installing @microsoft/generator-sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-framework

When I install  @microsoft/generator-sharepoint, I get below error. Kindly note that my node version is v6.11.0 and npm version is 5.0.3
[image]

What can be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the latest version of NodeJS. You can check the latest version using

```
node -v
```

Follow the full procedure here: [SharePoint Framework - Set up your SharePoint client-side web part development environment](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)

Comment: Ronak please read my question. BTW I have latest node and npm but I have issue @microsoft/generator-sharepoint

Comment: Yeah.. but make sure that you are following all the steps in the link above. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

SPFx build pipeline does NOT currently support npm v5.x, so you'll need to use either v3 or v4. At the time of the writing, NodeJS LTS version (v6.11.0) installs npm v3.10.10.

You can downgrade to older npm version with following command `npm install -g npm@3`.

You can check below SPFx article for complete details

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/staging/docs/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment.md